# How to SELECT rows from table A that do not match with table B (using time range, based from table B)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Im a student, trying to design a system that can find ALL vacant rooms at a certain time and day, given the schedules of professors based from the existing database of their school.
For each rooms, a schedule is generated from 7:30:00 - 19:30:00 (incremental by 00:30:00) to the table named **'room_schedule'**. Each schedule of a room is referenced  by room_id from another table named ***'room_details'***. On the other hand, 
the table 'room_details' is linked to table **'prof_schedule'** by room. Schedules of professors are recorded on an existing table 'prof_schedule'.

Here's how the tables look like

```
    TABLE 'room_schedule'

    day    time_start  time_end    room_id
    MWF    07:00:00    07:30:00    36
    MWF    07:30:00    08:00:00    36
    MWF    08:00:00    08:30:00    36
    MWF    08:30:00    09:00:00    36
    MWF    09:00:00    09:30:00    36
    MWF    09:30:00    10:00:00    36
    MWF    07:00:00    07:30:00    37
    MWF    07:30:00    08:00:00    37
    MWF    08:00:00    08:30:00    37
    MWF    08:30:00    09:00:00    37
    MWF    09:00:00    09:30:00    37
    MWF    09:30:00    10:00:00    37

    TABLE 'room_details'
    room_id     room_name      room       
    36          Biology Room   309   
    37          Physics Room   307


    TABLE 'prof_schedule'
    sched_id   professor       Day  room    time_start  time_end   subj
    1          Jeffrey Smith   MWF  309     8:00:00     9:30:00     Biology
    2          Ben Williams    MWF  307     8:30:00     10:00:00    Physics
```

Based from the schedules of professors, i wanted the result for vacant rooms to be like this

```
RESULT vacant rooms
        day    time_start  time_end    room_name
        MWF    07:00:00    07:30:00    Biology Room
        MWF    07:30:00    08:00:00    Biology Room
        MWF    09:30:00    10:00:00    Biology Room
        MWF    07:00:00    07:30:00    Physics Room
        MWF    07:30:00    08:00:00    Physics Room
        MWF    08:00:00    08:30:00    Physics Room
```

I have tried the query below, but it seems like it removes all records from 'room_schedule' having time_start and time_end from 'prof_schedule'

```
SELECT day, time_start, time_end,  room_name 
FROM room_details AS rd 
INNER JOIN room_schedule AS rs 
ON rd.room_ID=rs.room_ID 
WHERE (
   (time_start NOT IN(SELECT time_start FROM prof_schedule)) AND 
   (time_end NOT IN (SELECT time_end FROM prof_schedule)) AND 
   (rs.day NOT IN (select day from prof_schedule)) AND 
   (rs.room_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT rd.room_ID from room_details AS rd 
    INNER JOIN prof_schedule AS ps on rd.room=ps.room))
  )
```

Can someone suggest a query that would show the result I mentioned?

P.S.
The design of the 3rd table (prof_schedule) needs to be retained because they'll be importing these from their existing system to the system I'm designing.

Comment: If we know that each room can be booked in half hour slots from 7:30:00 - 19:30:00, then we don't really need the room_schedule table. We just need to know when the room is unavailable.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your response...does it mean I used the room_schedule table wrongly? Haha.  I have seen some posts similar to what you have said.But let's suppose I removed the room_schedule table, then Room A will be used on MWF, from 8:00 - 9:00, how would I display that Room A will be vacant from 7:30 -8:00 and for the rest of remaining hours ('til19:30) every MWF?

Comment: MWF is "Mondays, Wednesdays, and Fridays"?

Comment: yes, and that's the way they recorded it in their database
"MWF" "TTH" "SAT"

Comment: 'Their database'. I thought this was your design ?!?!

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to say. Im adapting the existing database of the school I'm creating the system for. Im the one who designed the first two tables, and they're asking me to show vacant rooms based on their data from the third table.

Comment: This is quite a big task. If someone doesn't beat me to it, I may try to give you a few pointers later, but I'm not sure that I can provide a comprehansive answer.

Comment: It's a big task because the current design isn't very good!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this and let me know.

```
SELECT a.day, a.time_start, a.time_end, b.room_name 
FROM `room_schedule` a 
INNER JOIN `room_details` b ON a.room_id = b.room_id
INNER JOIN `prof_schedule` c ON b.room = c.room AND 
IF(a.time_end > c.time_start, a.time_start >= c.time_end, a.time_start < c.time_start)
```

---

Try using `GROUP BY` clause like this

```
SELECT a.*, b.room_name 
FROM `room_schedule` a 
INNER JOIN `room_details` b ON a.room_id = b.room_id
INNER JOIN `prof_schedule` c ON b.room = c.room AND 
IF(a.time_end > c.time_start, a.time_start >= c.time_end, a.time_start < c.time_start)
GROUP BY a.room_id, a.time_start, a.time_end
```

Comment: Your query worked but it just returned all rows and tripled some of them...

Comment: As per the data you've provided above, I tried at my end it is giving me exact same output like you mentioned, without any duplicate records.

Comment: the data that tripled are those that matched with prof_schedule

Comment: ill try it again, maybe i overlooked something

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting duplicate records. We can also group the results but here I thought it's not required. Just let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: Sweet. It worked using only the data i supplied above, but when I applied it to the entire records in the table, that's when duplicating of records occur.

Comment: Thanks for this. It works,  maybe i should just fix other data that were inputted.

Comment: Just check grouping the results works for you or not. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I don't understand why down vote my answer? What's the reason?